# Правильно ли работает upper_bound?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl, списки

Пусть есть:

```
class MySet {
   int *set_;
   int countOfElements_;
public: ...
};
```

В `main()` я создаю контейнер `list<MySet>` и добавляю в него элементы.

Вот так выглядит контейнер после добавления элементов и сортировке их по количеству элементов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем я создал итератор и сдвинул его на 5 позиций:

```
list<MySet>::iterator temp = mylist.begin();
advance(temp, 5);
```

Теперь мне необходимо применить алгоритмы `lower_bound` и `upper_bound` к этому контейнеру.

```
auto lower = lower_bound(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), *temp, mySortFunction2);
cout << "\nLower_bound: " << *lower;
auto upper = upper_bound(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), *temp, mySortFunction2);
cout << "\nUpper_bound: " << *upper << endl;
```

Реализация:

```
bool mySortFunction2(MySet obj1, MySet obj2)
{
    return obj1.getSize() > obj2.getSize();
}
```

Результаты выполнения алгоритмов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ведь это же не правильно? Что нужно изменить для корректной работы?

Ещё вопрос: как реализовать `nth_element()`? Какой для него нужно написать предикат?

Comment: Не понятно, что вы хотите получить?

Comment: upper_bound же должен выводить первый элемент, больший данного, нет?

Comment: Он и вывел элемент, который "больше" согласно вашему критерию, так как вы упорядочиваете элементы по убыванию размера. То есть он выдает следующий после него по убыванию элемент.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: А как быть с nth_element()?

Comment: А что с ним? И зачем вам нужен этот алгоритм, если у вас список уже отсортирован? И более того, этот алгоритм не может работать ос списком, так как требуются итераторы прямого доступа.

Comment: например, применить его для неотсортированного списка.

Comment: Этот алгоритм не может работать ос списком. Как я уже написал, требуются итераторы прямого доступа, а у списка их нет.

Comment: Всё понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow по большому счёту сортировка и upper_bound тоже требуют прямого доступа. Если не думать об оптимизации то написать безусловно можно)

Comment: @pavel, сортировка может и не требовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В соответствии с этой функцией сравнения

```
bool mySortFunction2(MySet obj1, MySet obj2)
{
    return obj1.getSize() > obj2.getSize();
}
```

которую лучше было бы определить как

```
bool mySortFunction2( const &MySet obj1, const &MySet obj2)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return obj1.getSize() > obj2.getSize();
}
```

и, соответственно, с этим объявлением метод `getSize` также должен быть объявлен как константный, например,

```
int getSize() const;
```

элементы списка сортируются по убыванию поля размера  класса `MySet`.

Поэтому применяя алгоритм `upper_bound` для элемента с последовательностью чисел

```
9 1 5 7
```

вы получаете следующий за ним элемент списка в соответствии с убыванием размера. Таким элементом является элемент с последовательностью чисел

```
8 5 4
```

Что касается алгоритма `std::nth_element`, то, во-первых, его имеет смысл применять к неотсортированным последовательностям, а, во-вторых, он требует наличие итераторов прямого доступа, а стандартный класс `std::list` не имеет итераторов данной категории. Поэтому вы не можете применить этот алгоритм к списку.

Вы могли бы выбрать другой контейнер для хранения ваших объектов, как, например, `std::deque`.

Comment: Разве у дека есть произвольный доступ?

Comment: @Qwertiy  Да, он поддерживает итераторы прямого доступа.

Comment: Действительно. Хотя и странно. Зачем бы ему?

Comment: @Qwertiy Для меня сейчас более интересен вопрос: наберу ли я сегодня на SO 300 баллов репутации, как это было вчера, или нет.:)